# netsuite inventory detail subrecord

Tags: inventory

I'm trying to populate the Inventory Detail subrecord on line items of a sales order through scripting.
The script is a user event script and will run on before submit.
At this point the user has already entered line item information:  ie.  item, quantity, lot number (a custom select field, where the options are inventory numbers).

I use the following to populate the inventory detail subrecords:

```
for (var i=1; i<=numberOfLineItems; i++){
nlapiSelectLineItem('item',i);
//First get the Lot Number and Quantity
var lotNumber = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_select_lot_number');
var quantity = nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity');

var inventoryDetail=nlapiCreateCurrentLineItemSubrecord('item','inventorydetail');

inventoryDetail.selectNewLineItem('inventoryassignment');
inventoryDetail.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventorydetail', 'issueinventorynumber', lotNumber);
inventoryDetail.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventorydetail', 'quantity', quantity);
inventoryDetail.commitLineItem('inventoryassignment');
inventoryDetail.commit();

nlapiCommitLineItem('item');}
```

When I do this I get the following error:

Notice (SuiteScript)
You must enter at least one line item for this transaction.

Does anyone have any ideas why I'm getting this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are errors on lines 10 and 11.  Also, in my particular case where I'm in the Customer Center, I needed to place this code in After Submit and load the record.  Here is the corrected code:

```
for (var i=1; i<=numberOfLineItems; i++){
        SOrecord.selectLineItem('item',i);
        //First get the Lot Number and Quantity
        var lotNumber = SOrecord.getCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'custcol_select_lot_number');
        var quantity = SOrecord.getCurrentLineItemValue('item', 'quantity');
        var available = SOrecord.getCurrentLineItemValue('item','available');
        nlapiLogExecution('debug','lineNum, LotNumID, Quantity, available',i + ', ' + lotNumber + ', ' + quantity + ', ' + available);

        var inventoryDetail = SOrecord.createCurrentLineItemSubrecord('item','inventorydetail');

        inventoryDetail.selectNewLineItem('inventoryassignment');
        inventoryDetail.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'issueinventorynumber', lotNumber);
        inventoryDetail.setCurrentLineItemValue('inventoryassignment', 'quantity', quantity);
        inventoryDetail.commitLineItem('inventoryassignment');
        inventoryDetail.commit();

        SOrecord.commitLineItem('item');

    }
    nlapiSubmitRecord(SOrecord);
```

Comment: @maty77 Peter could you help me on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63343560/how-to-get-netsuite-bin-number-details-from-inventory-details-tab-using-soap-api